# PHP - Updating cart total amount without page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**Bottom Line Up Front:** I am trying to update the cart total amount in the checkout page, to be precise, on the header area where all the navigation links are stored and also in the confirm order accordion. In order to do that I have to refresh the page. How can I try to achieve it without page refresh ?

**Detailed Information**: When the user comes to the checkout page, he has to fill out the shipping form in order to apply the shipping rate. This is normally a select box where he will choose the region depending upon his shipping address. After selecting the region and clicking on the button, I am calling the `$.ajax` method to insert into the database table and it does get inserted correctly.

Once it is done, the next accordion comes up asking the confirmation of the cart where in he will see the complete details of the cart. Over there I want to show the updated cart amount, meaning, `the cart total amount + the shipping zone amount` which the user has to pay.

I can successfully get the updated cart total amount but cannot show it to the user. The user has to refresh the page every time in order to see the updated cart total amount. This in turn leads to the procedure once again starting from choosing the shipping zone which should not happen.

Question: How do I update the session value on click of the button which is in the shipping zone and display it to the user without page refresh on both side - In the header area and also in the confimation accordion ? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank You.

Here's my select box to choose the zone:

```
<select name="selectZone" id="custDelAddZone">
    <option value="-1">----- Select -----</option>
    <?php
    $queryForZone = "SELECT * FROM shipZones";
    $validate->Query($queryForZone);
    if ($validate->NumRows() >= 1) {
        while ($row = $validate->FetchAllDatas()) {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['Id'].'">'.$row['Name'].'</option>';
        }
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Here's my checkout page (Confirmation Accordion):

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_SESSION['cart'] ) && $_SESSION['cart'] != "" ) {
    $total = 0;
    $subTotal = 0; $sbTotal = 0;
    $taxAmount = $tax = $totalTaxAmount = $taxAmt = 0;
    $cartWeightPerProduct = $totalCartWeight = $amtWeight = 0;

    $sql = "SELECT p.*, c.*, ws.* FROM products p, categories c, weight_shipping ws WHERE ProdCode IN (";
    foreach ( $_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value ) {
        $sql .= '"'.$id.'",';
    }
    $sql = substr( $sql, 0, -1 ) . ") AND p.CatId = c.CatId AND ws.ProdId = p.ProdId";
    if ($validate->Query($sql) == TRUE) {
        if ($validate->NumRows() >= 1) {
            while ( $row = $validate->FetchAllDatas() ) {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td><img src="images/Products/'.$row['ProdCode'].'.jpg" alt="'.$row['ProdCode'].'"><a href="product.php?code='.$row['ProdCode'].'">'.$row['ProdName'].'</a></td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['ProdCode'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>Rs. '.$row['ProdRate'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$_SESSION['cart'][$row['ProdCode']]['quantity'].'</td>';

                $sbTotal = $row['ProdRate'] * $_SESSION['cart'][$row['ProdCode']]['quantity'];
                $subTotal = $sbTotal;
                echo '<td>'.number_format($sbTotal,2).'</td>';
                $total += $subTotal;
                $_SESSION['cartTotalAmount'] = $total;
                $tax = $row['CatTaxPercent'];
                $taxAmt = (($sbTotal * $tax ) / 100);
                $taxAmount += $taxAmt;
                $amt = 0;
                $cartWeightPerProduct = ($row['weight'] * $_SESSION['cart'][$row['ProdCode']]['quantity']);
                echo '</tr>';
                $totalCartWeight += $cartWeightPerProduct;
            }
            $totalTaxAmount += $taxAmount;

            $_SESSION['cartWeight'] = $totalCartWeight;

            $sessAmnt = ($total + $totalTaxAmount);
            $totalPayableAmnt = $sessAmnt + $_SESSION['TotalWeight'];

            $_SESSION['sessionTotalPayable'] = number_format($totalPayableAmnt, 2);
            if ( isset( $_SESSION['sessionTotalPayable'] ) ) {
                $amt = $totalPayableAmnt;
            } else {
                $amt = "Rs. 0";
            }

            echo '<tr><td>Cart Total:</td><td>'.number_format($total,2).'</td></tr>';

            echo '<tr><td>Taxes:</td><td>'.number_format($totalTaxAmount,2).'</td></tr>';

            echo '<tr><td>Shipping:</td><td>'.number_format($_SESSION['TotalWeight'],2).'</td></tr>';

            echo '<tr><td>Total Payable Amount:</td><td>'.number_format($amt,2).'</td></tr>';
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my AJAX code that I am using to insert:

```
$.ajax({
    var dataStr = $("#chooseShippingZoneForm").serialize();
    url: 'http://localhost/ECommerce/ActionFiles/Customers/UpdateDeliveryZone.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: dataStr,
    success: function(msg) {
        toastr.success(msg);
        toastr.options.showMethod = "slideDown";
        toastr.options.hideMethod = "slideUp";
    }
});
```

And here's the UpdateDeliveryZone.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$zoneId = $custCode = "";

require_once '../../Classes/class.Validation.php';
$validate = new Validation('developi_ecommerce');

$q = "SELECT CustCode FROM customers WHERE CustEmailAdd = '".$_SESSION['Customer']['email']."'";
$validate->Query($q);
if ($validate->NumRows() >= 1) {
    while ($row = $validate->FetchAllDatas()) {
        $custCode = $row['CustCode'];
    }
} else {
    echo "No Customer Found";
}

if ( isset( $_POST['selectZone'] ) && $_POST['selectZone'] != "" ) {
    $zoneId = $validate->EscapeString( $_POST['selectZone'] );
    $query = "UPDATE customers_delivery_address SET ZoneId = '".$zoneId."' WHERE CustCode = '".$custCode."' AND CustDelAddLastInserted >= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE";
    if ( $validate->Query( $query ) == TRUE ) {
        echo "Updated Successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Invalid Query";
    }
} else {
    echo "Value Not Set";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After selecting the region you are calling the $.ajax to post the data into the database.

Once the ajax request is successfully executed. Then return the success message, total amt, shipping zone etc in json format.

Then parse JSON and do the calculation and place the values in appropriate elements.

In the same way you can update the session on the client end by using sessionstorage() method.

**Sample jQuery Code**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "update.php",
  data: { **data to be passed** }
})
.done(function( resp ) {
    // Parse the response and place the values in appropriate sections

    $("#confirmdiv #totalPrice").html(resp.totalPrice);

    // Other sections that needs to be updated.
});
```